# Extracting programmatically a relation's secondary conditions

Tags: eloquent, laravel-8

I have a model called `Device`. In this model I have the following relation:

```
public function activeMeter()
{
    return $this->hasOneThrough(
        Meter::class,
        DeviceMeter::class,
        'device_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'meter_id'
    )
        ->whereNotNull('devices_meters.activated_at')
        ->whereNull('devices_meters.deactivated_at');
}
```

I then programmatically build a query for purposes of searches. The search code creates joins for tables in a `$searchables` list. All good up to here. I am wanting to add the "extra conditions" to my joins based on the relation conditions:

```
        ->whereNotNull('devices_meters.activated_at')
        ->whereNull('devices_meters.deactivated_at');
```

Starting with examples from `PowerJoins` I have the following method in my search trait:

```
public function applyExtraConditions($relation, $join)
{
    Log::info($relation->getQuery()->getQuery()->wheres);

    foreach ($relation->getQuery()->getQuery()->wheres as $index => $condition) {

        if (! in_array($condition['type'], ['Basic', 'Null', 'NotNull', 'Nested'])) {
            continue;
        }

        $method = "apply{$condition['type']}Condition";
        $this->$method($join, $condition);
    }
}
```

This is where this conditions data is contained:

```
$relation->getQuery()->getQuery()->wheres
```

The application of the conditions found through this process works, though the conditions do not make sense.

The `Log` shows, for this example:

```
[2022-01-18 09:41:26] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'Null',
    'column' => 'devices_meters.device_id',          <--------- Why is this here?
    'boolean' => 'and',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'NotNull',
    'column' => 'devices_meters.activated_at',       <--------- OK!
    'boolean' => 'and',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'Null',
    'column' => 'devices_meters.deactivated_at',     <--------- OK!
    'boolean' => 'and',
  ),
)
```

Doing a `dd` on the relation, I can see the `wheres` containing these:

```
  +wheres: array:3 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "type" => "Null"
      "column" => "devices_meters.device_id"
      "boolean" => "and"
    ]
    1 => array:3 [
      "type" => "NotNull"
      "column" => "devices_meters.activated_at"
      "boolean" => "and"
    ]
    2 => array:3 [
      "type" => "Null"
      "column" => "devices_meters.deactivated_at"
      "boolean" => "and"
    ]
  ]
```

This results in the following `SQL` syntax:

```
select
    *
from
    `devices`
    left join `devices_meters` on `devices_meters`.`device_id` = `devices`.`id`
    and `devices_meters`.`device_id` is null             <--------- Why is this here?
    and `devices_meters`.`activated_at` is not null      <--------- OK!
    and `devices_meters`.`deactivated_at` is null        <--------- OK! 
    ....
```

I get similar issues with Polymorphic and other relations:

```
// Site Model
public function address()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable');
}

[2022-01-18 09:41:26] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'Null',
    'column' => 'addresses.addressable_id',
    'boolean' => 'and',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'NotNull',
    'column' => 'addresses.addressable_id',
    'boolean' => 'and',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'type' => 'Basic',
    'column' => 'addresses.addressable_type',
    'operator' => '=',
    'value' => 'App\\Models\\Site',
    'boolean' => 'and',
  ),
)  

left join `addresses` on `addresses`.`addressable_id` = `sites`.`id`
and `addresses`.`addressable_id` is null
and `addresses`.`addressable_id` is not null
and `addresses`.`addressable_type` = 'App\Models\Site'
```

Why am I getting these "extra" conditions? Or is there a better way to access just the conditions in the relation?

Answer (score 0):

I ignored the "extra links" by looking for any links where the primary key is null / notnull. Still do not know why these are there.